# if number is greater than but less than

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSTimer, and I want to detect if my timer greater than but less than a specific number..

```
if (MainInt is between 10-25) {
    NSLog(@"level1");
}
```

i tried something like

```
if (MainInt <= 25 && MainInt >= 10) {
    NSLog(@"level1");
}
```

Comment: That should work. What is the problem?

Comment: That should work. The problem is likely in some of the code you're not showing us.

Comment: Also normally we read from left to right. So >= 10 should be before <=25.

Comment: _"i tried something like"_ What happened when you tried that? What's the problem with that solution?  If you give a solution to your own problem, its good to describe how that solution doesn't work for you. In this case, that snippet is exactly what you need.  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @BlackFrog Not everyone in the world [reads left to right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Worst case scenario you can use 2 if statements:

```
if (MainInt < 25) {
   if(MainInt > 10){
       NSLog(@"level1");
    }
}
```

This way you can know for sure errors are not coming from your IF statement